# Multiple anonymous IIFEs inside outer function

Tags: javascript

I have a `scrollHandler` function which contains all of my `scroll` event-listener logic.

I've used multiple IIFE's inside to separate the logic:

```
import skills from './json/skills.json';

let capToggle = false;
let triggerCalculateHeight = false;
let scrollEnd = false;

function headingFadeIn(heading) {
    if (!heading) return;
    const parent = heading.parentNode.parentNode;
    const triggerHeight = parent.offsetTop - window.innerHeight / 1.5;

    if (window.scrollY > triggerHeight) {
        heading.style.opacity = '1';
    } else heading.style.opacity = '0';
}

export default function scrollHandler() {
    // Headings
    (() => {
        headingFadeIn(document.getElementById('portfolio-heading'));
        headingFadeIn(document.getElementById('skills-heading'));
        headingFadeIn(document.getElementById('bio-heading'));
        headingFadeIn(document.getElementById('contact-heading'));
    })();
    // Skills
    (() => {
        const bars = document.querySelectorAll('.skill-bar');
        if (!bars) return;

        bars.forEach((i, index) => {
            const bottom = i.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;

            if (window.scrollY > bottom && !i.dataset.heightCalculated) {
                i.style.transform = `scale3d(1, ${skills[index].height / 10}, 1)`;
                i.setAttribute('data-height-calculated', true);

                capToggle = true;
                triggerCalculateHeight = true;
            }
        });
    })();
    // Reviews
    (() => {
        const el = document.getElementById('reviews-inner');
        if (!el) return;

        const mainBackground = document.getElementById('ul-bg');
        const backgrounds = document.querySelectorAll('.blockquote-bg');
        const texts = document.querySelectorAll('.reviews-toggle');
        const bound = el.getBoundingClientRect().top * 10;

        if (window.scrollY > bound) {
            mainBackground.style.opacity = '1';
            mainBackground.style.transform = 'scale(1) rotate(45deg)';
            backgrounds.forEach(i => (i.style.opacity = '1'));
            backgrounds[0].style.transform = 'translate(-4%, -9%) skew(45deg)';
            backgrounds[1].style.transform = 'translate(-6%, -2%) skew(45deg)';
            backgrounds[2].style.transform = 'translate(-5%, 1%) skew(45deg)';
            texts.forEach(i => (i.style.opacity = '1'));
        }
    })();
    // Bio
    (() => {
        const container = document.getElementById('bio-container');
        const tabSelected = document.getElementById('tab-selected');
        const tabBackground = document.getElementById('tab-background');
        const height = document.getElementById('bio').offsetTop;
        if (!tabBackground || !container || !tabSelected || !height) return;

        if (window.scrollY > height / 1.1) {
            // Background tab styling
            tabBackground.style.left = `${tabSelected.offsetLeft}px`;
            tabBackground.style.maxWidth = `${tabSelected.offsetWidth + 20}px`;

            // Container transition
            container.style.opacity = '1';
            container.style.transform = 'skew(-25deg)';
            container.childNodes[0].style.transform = 'skew(25deg)';
        }
    })();
    // Contact
    (() => {
        const groups = document.querySelectorAll('.form-group');
        if (!groups) return;

        groups.forEach((i, index) => {
            i.childNodes[1].blur();

            if (window.scrollY > (i.getBoundingClientRect().top * 10) / 1.5) {
                i.style.opacity = '1';

                if (index >= groups.length - 1) scrollEnd = true;
            }
        });
    })();

    return { capToggle, triggerCalculateHeight, scrollEnd };
}
```

Is this considered *good* practice? Are there any pitfalls that could come from this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Modules** You're already using `export` syntax, so you're currently in a module. Rather than defining multiple IIFEs, you might consider using separate sub-modules:

```
// fadeInHeadings.js

// Renaming from headingFadeIn to fadeInHeading for readability
function fadeInHeading(heading) {
    if (!heading) return;
    const parent = heading.parentNode.parentNode;
    const triggerHeight = parent.offsetTop - window.innerHeight / 1.5;

    if (window.scrollY > triggerHeight) {
        heading.style.opacity = '1';
    } else heading.style.opacity = '0';
}

export const fadeInHeadings = () => {
  const headingIds = [
    'portfolio-heading',
    'skills-heading',
    'bio-heading',
    'contact-heading',
  ];
  for (const id of headingIds) {
    fadeInHeading(document.getElementById(id));
  }
};
```

```
// scrollHandler.js
import { fadeInHeadings } from './fadeInHeadings';
import { transformBars } from './transformBars';
import { transformReviews } from './transformReviews';

export default function scrollHandler() {
  fadeInHeadings();

  const { capToggled, newTriggerCalculateHeight } = transformBars();
  capToggle ||= capToggled;
  triggerCalculateHeight ||= newTriggerCalculateHeight;

  transformReviews();

  // ...
```

This way, when, for example, a review isn't scaling properly, you can navigate directly to `transformReviews` to debug and fix the problem, rather than wander around in a significantly larger file looking for where reviews are referenced.

**Variable names and iteration** Your two `forEach`es are a bit confusing:

```
bars.forEach((i, index) => {
```

When `i` is used as a variable name, it's almost always used to reference the *index* of a collection. To have `i` not only not refer to an index, but to also have an `index` variable, is confusing. Instead, consider:

```
bars.forEach((bar, index) => {
```

Same sort of thing in `Contact`:

```
const groups = document.querySelectorAll('.form-group');
if (!groups) return;
groups.forEach((i, index) => {
```

`i` should probably be renamed to `formGroup` or something similar. Also, `querySelectorAll` will return an array-like NodeList. Even if it's empty, it'll never be falsey, so you can remove the `if (!groups) return;` line.

**children** You have

```
formGroup.childNodes[1].blur();
```

`childNodes` returns a collection that *includes text nodes*. Text nodes can be empty, and including them in a collection can make logic more tedious than it needs to be. Since you want to select an *element* with that, better to use `.children` (which only returns element children nodes), so you can do

```
formGroup.children[1].blur();
// or
formGroup.children[0].blur();
// or, be more specific and use a CSS selector
formGroup.querySelector(<some-selector>).blur();
```

**Persistent variables?** The persistent module variables seem a bit odd. If they really need to be in persistent state, it might make sense to expose a function that returns their current values. If they aren't meant to be persistent, initialize them to `false` inside `scrollHandler` instead - or, inside the sub-module which reassigns its value, which is returned to `scrollHandler` and then returned by `scrollHandler`. For example, it'd be great if you could do this:

```
// showFormGroups.js
export const showFormGroups = () => {
    const groups = document.querySelectorAll('.form-group');
    let scrollEnd = false;
    groups.forEach((formGroup, index) => {
        formGroup.children[1].blur();
        if (window.scrollY > (formGroup.getBoundingClientRect().top * 10) / 1.5) {
            formGroup.style.opacity = '1';
            if (index >= groups.length - 1) {
                scrollEnd = true;
            }
        }
    });
    return scrollEnd;
};
```

```
// scrollHandler.js
export default function scrollHandler() {
    // ...
    const scrollEnd = showFormGroups();
    // ...
    return { capToggle, triggerCalculateHeight, scrollEnd };
```

**Styles into CSS** You have

```
if (window.scrollY > bound) {
    mainBackground.style.opacity = '1';
    mainBackground.style.transform = 'scale(1) rotate(45deg)';
    backgrounds.forEach(i => (i.style.opacity = '1'));
    backgrounds[0].style.transform = 'translate(-4%, -9%) skew(45deg)';
    backgrounds[1].style.transform = 'translate(-6%, -2%) skew(45deg)';
    backgrounds[2].style.transform = 'translate(-5%, 1%) skew(45deg)';
    texts.forEach(i => (i.style.opacity = '1'));
}
```

To apply this logic, I think it'd make more sense to put the CSS rules in your CSS file, and then just toggle a class. Something like:

```
// SCSS for brevity
body.showReviews {
  #ul-bg {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1) rotate(45deg);
  }
  .blockquote-bg {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .blockquote-bg:nth-of-type(1) {
    transform: translate(-4%, -9%) skew(45deg);
  }
  .blockquote-bg:nth-of-type(2) {
    transform: translate(-6%, -2%) skew(45deg);
  }
  .blockquote-bg:nth-of-type(3) {
    transform: translate(-5%, 1%) skew(45deg);
  }
  .reviews-toggle {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```
// transformReviews.js
export const transformReviews = () => {
  const el = document.getElementById('reviews-inner');
  if (!el) return;
  const bound = el.getBoundingClientRect().top * 10;
  document.body.classList.toggle('showReviews', window.scrollY > bound);
};
```

**Framework** On a larger scale, all of this careful element selecting, iterating, examining, and manual manipulation of the DOM seems a bit tedious. For a professional project that isn't tiny, I would prefer to look into a framework like React to tie element state directly to their respective DOM elements.

Comment: This is very in-depth! Really appreciate it. When I'm not bleary-eyed I'll give it a full look over

Comment: Never mind, I couldn't help myself. This is brilliant, lot's of helpful tips. I'll definitely put some of these into practice, thanks again